# Reset input value without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, submit

I'm trying to disable a search submit button if my forms input is empty, this works fine if nothing has been searched for but if I submit a search and then (once the page loads) clear the search input and click submit again, the button isn't disabled.

I'm disabling the submit button using this code

`$("#searchform input#search-submit").click(function() {
        var sValue = $('#searchform input#s').val();
        if (sValue != "") {
            $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });`

I've worked out that the issue is the input field is retaining whatever value I searched for previously and so the button isn't disabled as it checks the input value and thinks its not empty.

Is there a way to delete an input value automatically once you've cleared the input field without refreshing the page?

**Update:**

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7zwT/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i included the Jsfiddle link with your expected result, see the below link you will get the result.

```
$("#searchform input#searchsubmit").click(function() {
    var sValue = $('#searchform input#s').val();
    if (sValue != "") {
        $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        return true;
    } else {
        $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        return false;
    }
return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7zwT/30/

Answer (score 1):

I think binding your click with live or on will help you out 
`$("#searchform input#searchsubmit").click(function(e) {
        var sValue = $('#searchform input#s').val();
        alert(sValue)
        if (sValue != "") {
            $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            e.preventDefault()
            $('form#searchform input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
 });`

Comment: I've tried using your code but the input is still retaining it's value

Comment: I've added a link to a fiddle on my question

Comment: check this out if it is helpful all u need to do is enable search button on focus out of text box

Answer (score 1):

If you click the search button when the input `#s` is empty, the button turns into disabled.
Then it cannot be pressed again, neither being reenabled.
Try it on another event like `changed` or `keypress`:

```
$('form#searchform input#s').changed(function() ...
```

Also take in account that, depending on the jQuery version (1.9 or above), you have to enable and disable (or add/remove the check mark) controls with `.prop()`:

```
$('form#searchform input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
```

More info about [how migrating to jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-)

Comment: disabling the button isn't really the issue, it's clearing the input value without refreshing

Comment: but where you are trying to clear the input content? I can't see it.

Comment: Sorry, my questions description wasn't great, I'm not clearing it using Jquery, This is just if you're deleting the input text on the page using backspace/cut